BigQuery "Unrecognized name" error in the SQL code has run?
I ran once code for similar data but it was "Unrecognized name: <column_name>". Details below:
I ran below code on Bigquery:
create table `Cyclist_data.2020` as
select
  ride_id, rideable_type, started_at, ended_at, member_casual,
  extract(time FROM started_at) as start_time,
  extract(day from started_at) as start_day,
  extract(month from started_at) as start_month,
  extract(year from started_at) as start_year,
  extract(dayofweek from started_at) as start_weekday,
  extract(time FROM ended_at) as end_time,
  extract(day from ended_at) as end_day,
  extract(month from ended_at) as end_month,
  extract(year from ended_at) as end_year,
  extract(dayofweek from ended_at) as end_weekday,
  ST_distance(
    st_geogpoint(start_lng, start_lat),
    st_geogpoint(end_lng, end_lat),
    false
  ) as distance_m
from
  `Cyclist_data.*`
WHERE
  ENDS_WITH(_TABLE_SUFFIX, '_2020');




create table `Cyclist_data.2021` as
select
  ride_id, rideable_type, started_at, ended_at, member_casual,
  extract(time FROM started_at) as start_time,
  extract(day from started_at) as start_day,
  extract(month from started_at) as start_month,
  extract(year from started_at) as start_year,
  extract(dayofweek from started_at) as start_weekday,
  extract(time FROM ended_at) as end_time,
  extract(day from ended_at) as end_day,
  extract(month from ended_at) as end_month,
  extract(year from ended_at) as end_year,
  extract(dayofweek from ended_at) as end_weekday,
  ST_distance(
    st_geogpoint(start_lng, start_lat),
    st_geogpoint(end_lng, end_lat),
    false
  ) as distance_m
from
  `Cyclist_data.*`
WHERE
  ENDS_WITH(_TABLE_SUFFIX, '_2021');

Eveything with 2021 is exactly like 2020. But when 2020's code complete, 2021 was Unrecognized name: start_lng. I'm sure there are start_lng columns in _2021 tables. Below is run log and _2021's schema.


Thanks for all answer!!

Didn't your first statement create a table in that dataset without a start_lng column?

@nitind yes, but In normal start_lng reference to the tables already exist not created table.

Your first statement creates a table with the same name pattern matching your 'from' clause in the 2nd query, but it doesn't have start_lng column. Maybe you can put both between BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT TRANSACTION statements?

hi @tinazmu how should I add it? I added begin before create and commit after where clause. Is it right?

Your first statement creates a table with the same name pattern matching your 'from' clause in the 2nd query, but it doesn't have start_lng column. Maybe you can put both between BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT TRANSACTION statements?
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

create table `Cyclist_data.2020` as
select
  ride_id, ...
from
  `Cyclist_data.*`
WHERE
  ENDS_WITH(_TABLE_SUFFIX, '_2020');

create table `Cyclist_data.2021` as
select
  ride_id, ...
from
  `Cyclist_data.*`
WHERE
  ENDS_WITH(_TABLE_SUFFIX, '_2021');

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

